# Rings and formal smoothness

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$ without zero divisors. Let $\mathfrak{m}_A \subset A$ be a maximal ideal. Assume that $\operatorname{Spec}A$ is NOT smooth at the point $\mathfrak{m}_A$. Is it true then that we can find a local ring $(R,\mathfrak{m}_R)$ over $\mathbb{C}$ with nilpotent maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_R$ and residue field $\mathbb{C}$ a ring $\tilde{R} \twoheadrightarrow R$ with nilpotent kernel and a morphism $A \rightarrow R$ sending $\mathfrak{m}_A$ to $\mathfrak{m}_R$ that can not be extended to a morphism $A \rightarrow \tilde{R}$?

In other words we know that since $\operatorname{Spec}A$ is not smooth then it is not formally smooth so we can find $R$ and a surjection $\tilde{R} \twoheadrightarrow R$ with nilpotent kernel such that some morphism $\operatorname{Spec}R \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}A$ can not be extended to a morphism $\operatorname{Spec}\tilde{R} \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}A$. I am asking if $\operatorname{Spec} R$ can be chosen to be a nilpotent thickening of $\operatorname{Spec}(A/\mathfrak{m}_A) \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}A$.

Comment: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02HR should answer the question